# LXD export backup failed. Snapshot error

Tags: server, lxc, lxd, container

I tried to make lxc backup and get's error that failes on some snapshot for 2 years ago.

run test command
`lxc export backup /tank/local/lxd/backups-temp/backup_test.tar.gz -v`

Error message:
`Error: Create backup: Backup create: Snapshot "sunday-2019-12-01" in storage but not expected`

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
|       NAME        |       TAKEN AT       | EXPIRES AT | STATEFUL |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| friday            | 2022/03/11 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| monday            | 2022/03/14 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| saturday          | 2022/03/12 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-01-23 | 2022/01/23 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-01-30 | 2022/01/30 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-02-06 | 2022/02/06 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-02-13 | 2022/02/13 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-02-20 | 2022/02/20 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-02-27 | 2022/02/27 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-03-06 | 2022/03/06 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| sunday-2022-03-13 | 2022/03/13 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| thursday          | 2022/03/10 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| tuesday           | 2022/03/15 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
| wednesday         | 2022/03/16 02:02 CET |            | NO       |
+-------------------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```

Under path */var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/custom-snapshots/default_happydays-storage*

```
monday    sunday-2019-10-27  sunday-2019-11-17
saturday  sunday-2019-11-03  sunday-2019-11-24
```

I have found this folder and removed. But still it's not working. So it should bee some where else.
I have used lot of hours to figure out. Can somebody help me with the issue.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`

Comment: Sounds like an orphaned snapshot file the export spotted it and you'll need to delete it to get the export to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by my self solution.

Here is solution if you can't see in lxc snapshot list old backup.
Than run this command:

**1. List all snapshots**

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```

**2. Getting all list:**

```
NAME                                                                                                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2019-12-08                                               103M      -   816M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2019-12-15                                              71,4M      -   819M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2019-12-22                                              70,3M      -   822M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2019-12-29                                              67,4M      -   824M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2020-01-05                                              60,1M      -   828M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2020-01-12                                              77,3M      -   834M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2020-01-19                                                83M      -   838M  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2022-01-23                                               100M      -  44,6G  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2022-01-30                                              89,2M      -  44,6G  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2022-02-06                                              94,1M      -  44,6G  -
tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2022-02-13                                              91,3M      -  44,6G  -
```

**3. Destroy it by:**

```
sudo zfs destroy tank/lxd/containers/backup@snapshot-sunday-2019-12-15

sudo zfs destroy tank/lxd/containers/**snapshot name**
```